# How can I exit helm grep and return to helm window?

Tags: helm

I've bound <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> to `helm-find-files`. Since I am still getting used to helm, when looking at a file listing, I instinctively invoke <kbd>C-s</kbd> (which starts helm grep in a helm session but starts search in dired-mode) to let me type part of the desired filename to bring the mark to the desired file. I know that I should instead simply start typing to do so instead of pressing <kbd>C-s</kbd>.

But once I've entered helm grep, I don't know how to leave it other than <kbd>C-g</kbd>, which drops me out of helm. I'd like to simply return to the helm find files screen, since I may have navigated to a different directory, but I haven't found the key combination to do so. Resuming helm (`helm-resume`) after quitting just brings me to the helm grep screen.

Comment: `C-x C-f` (`helm-quit-and-find-file`) is designed for this purpose, however, it's buggy.

Comment: Helm's documentation is incomplete in such respects. It does not use the native info system, has a weird interface that is hard to discover. It is non-standard in many respects, not just C-s stumbling block.

Comment: `wrong type argument: stringp, nil` for `C-x C-f`. I did change helm prefix to `C-c h`, but I don't think that matters here.

Comment: @lefenzy I fixed that bug a few hours ago (I hope), you can update your helm and try again. `C-x C-f` is the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have `helm-resume` bounded to <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>.

To see all helm buffers I just pass it the universal argument <kbd>C-u C-x C-b</kbd>. I can then pick the one that I want.

Comment: Isn't `C-x C-b` the command `list-buffers` though? Funnily enough I can't call helm-resume using `M-x` because I've bound `M-x` to `helm-M-x` and it states I'm trying to start a helm session within a helm session. `C-u C-x C-b` does work although it is a bit cumbersome

Comment: Yeah, but since I use helm, I don't want to use `list-buffers` anymore.  Just bind `helm-resume` to something and use the universal argument. Try `C-u C-c h b`.

Comment: The thing is, I don't think `helm-resume` works because either I am already in the helm session or it just resumes back to the helm grep session. Your second suggestion of `C-x C-b` to list helm sessions works (universal argument seemingly not needed). Thanks.

Comment: If you exit first with `C-g`, then you can use the universal argument.

Comment: Right. To clarify, `C-x C-b` (universal argument not needed), which I have not modified in my configuration, invokes `helm-resume-list-buffers-after-quit` when in a helm session and `list-buffers` when not in a helm session. Helm-prefix, which I've bound to `C-c h`, followed by `b` resumes the helm session after a `C-g`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> (`helm-quit-and-find-file`) within any helm command will bring you to `helm-find-files`.

Comment: Yes "wrong type argument: stringp, nil" bug is fixed in "20160629.116" helm pacakge on melpa. Thanks

Comment: But I guess that `C-x C-b` while within helm is the universal answer for exiting helm grep and returning to whatever helm buffer you were in previously however, since launching helm grep is possible from various types of helm buffers.

Comment: @lefenzy I agree. I upvoted the current accepted answer.